# PyPi does not grab templates directory on a Django app

Tags: python, django, pypi

**What is my goal**

I want to publish a PyPI package where the code within this package will be a Django application (migrations + templates folder, views, models, etc...)

I created the project with `setup.py` which includes the necessary data so that the `build` module of python will build the PyPI package smoothly, with version management.
This is the repository for further look: [github-repo](https://github.com/jimdevops19/rlocker_expiry_addon)

**What is the problem**

The `python -m build` command does not take the templates directory within the package.

It leads to a broken package of a Django application, because when you attempt to install the ([package](https://pypi.org/project/rlocker-expiryaddon)), it does not bring the templates. It is testable with `pip install rlocker-expiryaddon`

**What did I try**

I know that mentioning a file inside `MANIFEST.in` will be responsible to grab the files in the build process. (?)
So I tried to inject the following line:

```
recursive-include templates *.html schema.js
```

Yet, no luck.

I know that there are a lot of open-source libraries like the `djangorestframework` that is easy downloadable via `pip` and it brings it's templates directory to the system interpreter as expected. But for me, I am not sure what is wrong.

Thanks for your help!